# get resource from a fragment

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to change the source of an ImageButton in android within a fragment.

I want to use the method Image.setImageResource() , however i can't use getResources() within the fragment. is there a way round this? getActivity().getResources() does not return any results unfortuantely.

I've tried writing a string such as "R.drawable." + {different image names} but i cannot convert that string to an int.

How else could this be done?

I just want to change some imageButtons with source files dependent on different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got this working in a fragment:

```
int imageresource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/your_image", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());        
    image.setImageResource(imageresource);
```

Comment: Also we can use resources from xml. for example getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.rose)

Answer (score 1):

`R.drawable.imagename` is an int.  And `setImageResource()` takes an int:

`imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename)`

Also, it's strange that `getActivity().getResources()` would return nothing.  If your Fragment is attached to an Activity, that should return a Resources object.

Comment: @AKTStudios `getActivity().getResources()` should work since `getResources` requires activity context. Post your implementation.

Comment: @user1380611 Hi all, Thanks for your answers it turns out the methods were working properly... and strangely only after i restarted eclipse did it find that the getResources() method was accessible locally... strange that. incidentally i got the image loading to work as i forgot to put in the "@drawable/"  - Thanks user1380611. Working now :-)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, you could set it as answer

Answer (score 0):

We can use resources in onCreateView(...) method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, container, false);
     int sizeView = rootView.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size_view));
     return view;
}
```